# GHC not fiding cabal package

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to run a haskell program I wrote but I am getting an error saying that cannot find cabal package.

This is the exact message that I am getting when I run ghci in my powershell

```
Loaded package environment from C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw32-9.6.2\environments\default
GHCi, version 9.6.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghc-9.6.2.exe: **can't find a package database at C:\cabal\store\ghc-9.6.2\package.db**
```

I am trying looking at the path C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw32-9.6.2\environments\default GHCi but it does not exist in my pc.

I tried to reinstall cabal but still does not work.

What should I do?